# Regex to catch specific shortcode

Tags: regex

I need to match `[tp lang="en"(Anything Here)[/tp]`

I have the following so far, but if if there are two shortcodes on a line, it will return from the first time `[tp lang="en"` to the last `[/tp]` on the line.

```
\[tp lang="en"(.*)\[/tp\]
```

How can I modify the above regex to match the first `[tp lang="en"` to the *first* `[/tp]` on the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a non-greedy operator.

```
\[tp lang="en"(.*?)\[/tp\]
```

Edit: Shouldn't the shortcode have a closing bracket?

```
[tp lang="en"](Anything Here)[/tp]
             ^Here
```

If so then it'll be

```
\[tp lang="en"\](.*?)\[/tp\]
```

Comment: `.*?` is a **non-greedy** operator.